Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code on xcode 15.3
when run react-native run-ios or run with xcode I have an error
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code.
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:6E42CF4B-E0CD-40CE-99F8-81AF07DEC3D5, OS:17.4, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:6E42CF4B-E0CD-40CE-99F8-81AF07DEC3D5, OS:17.4, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vincho-blolxiechfckjwewixzdfkxtcoiw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-rncore.build/Script-46EB2E0001DA30.sh (in target 'React-rncore' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

Remove all spaces in the project path
